# What is difference between Publish Binary and R-Binary (I guess this is Rendered Binary ?)

Tags: 2013-sp1, sdl-tridion

Can anyone explain - What is difference between Publish Binary and R-Binary (I guess this is Rendered Binary ?)

Not sure what am I asking here but this was one question asked by one my friend.. I am lost.. Can some one explain ?

Comment: honestly, never heard R-binary as a Tridion term

Comment: Mee too :) But Thanks for confirming.